# Keras incompatible data shape

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to train SegNet model with CamVid data. I got source code from https://github.com/ykamikawa/tf-keras-SegNet . However, I got following error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer conv2d_152 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: [360, 480, 3]
```

Train data shape is (233, 360, 480, 3). I read some solutions and they were saying I need to feed the model with (None, 360, 480, 3) shape data. How can I reshape my data to this dimensions.

I am using tensorflow2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a dataset from your data. The easy fix would be:

```
x = np.zeros((233, 360, 480, 3))
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(x).batch(1)
```

Assuming that the `x` is your given input(in my case all zeros), dataset will have the shape: `<BatchDataset shapes: (None, 360, 480, 3), types: tf.float64>`
But, I advise you to read the dataset section of the Tensorflow documentation [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset?hl=en).

Answer (score 0):

You are passing single images without batch dimension to the network. (otherwise `ndim` would be 4). Probably the batch dimension collapsed when you selected a single image with `train_data[i]`. Either try selecting an image with `train_data[i:i+1]` or add an dimension with `None` like this:

```
img = train_data[i]
img = img[None, :, :, :]
```

And then pass it to the nework.

One thing is for sure, you are not passing the full training data with `(233, 360, 480, 3)` dimensions to the network.